# How to convert animated PNG (APNG) into animated WEBP file?

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, webp, apng

I have been searching whole internet and yet still not a very good solution

I have searched thoroughly the webp of Google and I have failed to find APNG to WEBP

https://developers.google.com/speed/webp

I have checked Magick.NET of ImageMagick and no solution https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET

The only thing I have found working is apng2webp but it is very outdated : https://github.com/Benny-/apng2webp/releases

I am looking for a C# library or a command line exe which I can use like below

```
cmd /C ""path\exeName.exe" -q 100 -min_size -m 6 -mt "path\image.png" -o "path\image.webp""
```

I have installed ImageMagick-7.1.0-0-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe and tested this command but generated output file is static

a.png is animated png file

```
magick "c:/temp/a.png" "c:/temp/a.webp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagemagick needs to be told that the png is an animated png you need to run the following command and your IM needs to be atleast 7.0.10-35

> convert "apng:c:/temp/a.png" "c:/temp/a.webp"